# React loses CSS transition if element ordering changes

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

React **keys** are not working.

If I swap the position of two react elements (`item0` and `item1`) positioned with transform `transform: translate();` a css transition is triggered, only if the elements were rendered in the same order.

If I change the order of the render (position swap still the same but now item0 renders **after** item1), the css transition is **not triggered**.

It looks like react is deleting the DOM element and recreating it, even if **they have React keys set**.

Here is a simple JSfiddle with the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/santiagopuentep/vvpezbp9/2/

Here is a written explanation:

Two React elements (`item0` and `item1`) positioned with `transform: translate();` in css and with a **css transition** active for that transform.

The app renders a list of items using a layout.

The first layout is: 
`item0` at `translate(0px,0px);` and item1 at `translate(0px,50px);`.

The second layout with the same items but with positions flipped: 
`item0` at `translate(0px,50px);` and item1 at `translate(0px,0px);`.

Clicking on any of the two items changed the layout back and forth from the two, **swapping** their positions and thus **triggering the css transition** for the position change.

This works just **fine**, the transitions trigger correctly.

The **problem** happens if the second layout makes the item1 render **after** item0 (only change in render order, css translate positions still swapped), **the transition for the second element is lost**.

This looks like React is deleting the element instead of just reordering it, even if I have keys set.

Please help!

Comment: thats just how react optimize rendering on lists. read that here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I am using keys, but the problem is still there. It looks as if the keys are not working for the last element of the list if the elements are reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I confirm this issue, so workaround is:

```
lastOrder = []
render() {
    let cards=this.props.cardList
    // HERE I RESORT NEW LIST LIKE PREVIOUS IT
    if (this.lastOrder.length) cards.sort((a, b) => 
         (this.lastOrder.indexOf(a.id) - this.lastOrder.indexOf(b.id)))
    // AND SAVE LAST ORDER
    this.lastOrder = cards.map(card => card.id)
    return <div className='board'>
            {cards.map(card => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />)}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem is that we can't use this one due to its performance. Sorting in each render would be very taxing.