# CSS transition when sorting a list

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a simple css background transition on the rows of a table as items go from inactive to active.

The transition should fade from blue (active === false) to pink (active === true).

The transition works as expected when going from blue to pink and the order changes, but not when going from pink to blue and the order changes.

I've made a simple example of my problem https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-8pf4s

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be just how React handles list reconciliation.

When the top item is turning inactive, it's first removed from the DOM and then appended as a new child. Which is why there is no transition. The transition works when you're turning the bottom item active as it's again the top item that's getting removed, so the transitioning item stays in the DOM.

Having keys on the table rows in this particular scenario doesn't help since, as far as I can tell from [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children), they are only used for optimization and do not actually guarantee the same DOM elements will be re-used.

You might stumble across the same problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508944/react-loses-css-transition-if-element-ordering-changes).

You could look into some libraries for transitioning lists to find a potential solution. E.g. [react-flip-move](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/react-flip-move)

Part of me hopes that I'm wrong cause it kinda sucks and makes a simple thing quite complicated.

Comment: Thanks Z! Yeah this makes sense. And yeah it sucks!

Answer (score 1):

This is strange behaviour, but I assume that as react is controlling inserting the dom node in its new position, the class is already added and so renders immediately. To counteract this I have created a keyframe animation and a stack of ids that are animating to apply this animation to. I could confirm that the same element was being reused (and not destroyed and recreated) by logging refs as they were created.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-dijkstra-ifren

```js
const App = () => {
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState([]);
  const removeAnimation = id => {
    setAnimating(animating.filter(x => x !== id));
  };

  const [data, setData] = useState(sourceData);
  const toggle = id => {
    let data2 = [...data];
    const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    data2[index] = { ...data2[index], active: !data2[index].active };
    setAnimating([...animating, data2[index].id]);
    data2 = [...data2.filter(x => x.active), ...data2.filter(x => !x.active)];
    setData(data2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(d => (
        <div
          key={d.id}
          className={cl(
            "row",
            d.active && "row_active",
            !d.active && animating.includes(d.id) && "row_hasAnimation",
            d.active && animating.includes(d.id) && "row_active_hasAnimation"
          )}
          onAnimationEnd={() => removeAnimation(d.id)}
        >
          <div className="cell">{d[1]}</div>
          <div className="cell">{d[2]}</div>
          <div className="cell">{d[3]}</div>
          <div className="cell">
            <button onClick={() => toggle(d.id)}>Toggle</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The data needs to be sorted. `active` items at the top. If I use `data` rather than `sortedData` then the order won't change

Comment: As a test can you changed it to `const sortedData = [...data.filter(x => x.active),...data.filter(x => !x.active)];` and let me know if that is desired behaviour, otherwise I don't think I understand what desired transition should look like

Comment: I've updated my example so both items are blue (not active) to start. If you click the bottom one it will move up and transition pink. That is the desired effect and is working. If you make them both pink, then click the top one, it will move down and turn blue, but without a transition. This is the problem.

Comment: Strange. I recreated your example to rule out any strange errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-rgb-lb2mz but it still has the problem. I created it with class component https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-curran-17xls and the problem is still there :/

Comment: See updated answer with animation on toggling active/inactive. Not the nicest solution, but prevents having to mess directly with the dom

Comment: tbh I found your code very difficult to read and @zdenek's answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: Is the fade effect in the example I linked what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah it's pretty close. Was hoping for a simpler solution though. Will likely use a library if we decide to animate this, as future devs looking wouldn't be happy trying to decipher what's going on.

Comment: Yeh, it's not the nicest solution. I faced a similar problem when trying to animate the position and size of an element: http://www.openchomp.com/ Drag controls from the right onto the grid on the left. The way it achieves this is the controls are position absolute and so never need to be reconciled by react - they are just moved. This is also complex but would solve your problem as well

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the sorting issue figured out for you, but the real stumper is the CSS issue..

The issue has to do with `keys` and creating mapping over items.. From what I make of it, React will apply the transition to a specific key.. After toggling to inactive, it's like React is treating it as a completely new node, and for some reason it doesn't correctly apply the transition..

I am not sure why this works one way but not the other, it's really odd to me... I was unable to find a fix online for this, and I tested a bunch of stuff.. You should look into CSS transitions with React and keys..

With that being said, I did come up with a few "hacky" ways to accomplish this..

***CSS AS JS OBJECTS:***

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const sourceData = [
  {
    id: "es",
    1: "uno",
    2: "dos",
    3: "tres",
    active: true
  },
  {
    id: "de",
    1: "eine",
    2: "zwei",
    3: "drei",
    active: false
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
    active: false
  }
];

const activeClass = {
  background: "pink",
  color: "blue",
  transition: "all 1s"
};

const inactiveClass = {
  background: "blue",
  color: "pink",
  transition: "all 1s"
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(sourceData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setClassNames();
  }, [data]);

  const sortData = d => d.sort((a, b) => (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 1));

  const sortAllData = d => [
    ...sortData(d.filter(i => i.active)),
    ...sortData(d.filter(i => !i.active))
  ];

  const handleToggle = index => event => {
    let clone = [...data];
    clone[index].active = !clone[index].active;
    setData(sortAllData(clone));
  };

  const setClassNames = () => {
    let actives = document.querySelectorAll(`[dataactive=${true}]`);
    let inactives = document.querySelectorAll(`[dataactive=${false}]`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      actives.forEach(a => {
        Object.keys(activeClass).forEach(k => a.style[k] = activeClass[k])
      });
      inactives.forEach(ina => {
        Object.keys(inactiveClass).forEach(k => ina.style[k] = inactiveClass[k])
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Active?</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((d, index) => {
            return (
              <tr dataactive={d.active.toString()} key={d.id} id={d.id}>
                <td>{d.active.toString()}</td>
                <td>{d[1]}</td>
                <td>{d[2]}</td>
                <td>{d[3]}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={handleToggle(index)}>TOGGLE</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

***USING A .CSS FILE:***

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const sourceData = [
  {
    id: "es",
    1: "uno",
    2: "dos",
    3: "tres",
    active: true
  },
  {
    id: "de",
    1: "eine",
    2: "zwei",
    3: "drei",
    active: false
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    1: "a",
    2: "b",
    3: "c",
    active: false
  }
];


const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(sourceData);

  useEffect(() => {
    setClassNames();
  }, [data]);

  const sortData = d => d.sort((a, b) => (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 1));

  const sortAllData = d => [
    ...sortData(d.filter(i => i.active)),
    ...sortData(d.filter(i => !i.active))
  ];

  const handleToggle = index => event => {
    let clone = [...data];
    clone[index].active = !clone[index].active;
    setData(sortAllData(clone));
  };

  const setClassNames = () => {
    let actives = document.querySelectorAll(`[dataactive=${true}]`);
    let inactives = document.querySelectorAll(`[dataactive=${false}]`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      actives.forEach(a => a.className = "active");
      inactives.forEach(ina => ina.className = "inactive");
    }, 10);
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles}>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Active?</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((d, index) => {
            return (
              <tr dataactive={d.active.toString()} key={d.id} id={d.id}>
                <td>{d.active.toString()}</td>
                <td>{d[1]}</td>
                <td>{d[2]}</td>
                <td>{d[3]}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={handleToggle(index)}>TOGGLE</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```css
.active {
  background: pink;
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.inactive {
  background: blue;
  color: pink;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and examples! Not sure I really want to use these in a production, but I'll weigh up my options. @Zdenek's response is technically correct

Comment: I can't say that I blame you. It bothers me this is so difficult to achieve. Glad you got the answer you were looking for, though. Cheers!